# command line options in perl

Tags: perl

I invoke my perl script by passing a number of command line options. If the required command line options are not passed by the user while invoking the script, the script should terminate.  Currently I'm doing a simple check using `if statement`.  If the required arguments are more than 10, using If statement looks clunky.  I'm just wondering if there is a better way to do it than just using an if statement.

Command line options :

```
sub startup {
   my ($self) = @_;

    GetOptions (
        "endpoint|e=s"           => \$self->{'endpoint'},
        "port|pt=s"              => \$self->{'port'},
        "client|c=s"             => \$self->{'client'},
        "client_interface|ci=s"  => \$self->{'client_interface'},
        "origin|o=s"             => \$self->{'origin'},
        "origin_interface|oi=s"  => \$self->{'origin_interface'},
        "customer_id|cid=s"      => \$self->{'customer_id'},
        "endpoint_id|eid=s"      => \$self->{'endpoint_id'},
         ) || $self->abort( "Invalid command line options.
               Valid options are endpoint,port,client,client_interface,
   origin,origin_interface,customer_id,endpoint_id");
```

#Terminate the script execution if --endpoint ip and --customer id and --client   are not passed

```
 if ( !$self->{'endpoint'} || !$self->{'customer_id'} || !$self->{'client'}){
        $self->abort( '[Startup] endpoint customer and client are required arguments.'
                      . 'Please provide --endpoint and --customer id and -- client  ');
    }
```

command to invoke the script :

```
./testframework --scriptname -- --endpoint=198.18.179.42  --port=5000 --client=1.1.1.1 --client_interface=2.2.2.2 --origin=3.3.3.3 --origin_interface= --Outertunnel=Tunnel0 --Innertunnel=Tunnel2 --customer_id=900010 --endpoint_id=2859588
```

Comment: I think your usage of `GetOptions` is correct. However, you are suffering of too many parameters which may indicate a design problem... do those arguments have reasonable defaults? Are they tied to a particular machine and therefore better suited to be part of a configuration file instead? Can they be guessed directly by your script instead of providing them as input? I would rather work on that.

Comment: @eballes IP's are different. There is nothing that i could get rid of from GetOptions.We have multiple test beds and we want the script to run on all the machines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version below removes some of the clunkiness while providing a more specific error message.

```
my @required = qw( endpoint customer_id client );

if ( my @missing = grep { !$self->{$_} } @required ) {
   $self->abort("[Startup] Missing required arguments: @missing");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `all` from [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html):

```
 unless ( all { defined $self->{$_} } qw(endpoint customer_id client) ){
    # error
 }
```

If you don't have a recent version of `List::Util`, use [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils)

Comment: How is your solution better than the one that i'm currently using. If i have 10 options, I need to specify all the options in qw(endpoint customer_id client option4 option 5...... option 10)  Which is pretty much similar to what i'm currently doing using an if stmt

Comment: @user3587025: Yes, this Answer still uses an if statement.  But, the incremental improvement is that you need to maintain less code because you need not have redundant `!$self->{'...'} ||`.  `Getopt::Long` has no inherent way to specify required options.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just check to see that you have the proper number of defined keys in your hash?

```
my @options = grep { defined $self->{$_} }  keys %{$self};
die "Missing options\n" unless @options == 10;
```

Or if you want your usage statement to be more explicit:

```
for my $opt (keys %{$self}) {
    die "Missing option --$opt\n" unless defined $self->{$opt};
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't distinguish between required and optional arguments.  I'm surprised it has the most votes.

Comment: I interpreted the original question to imply that all of the options were required.

Comment: but even if not, it could be easily modified.  Create `$self->{required} = {}`, and then change the `GetOptions` required parameters to point to a reference to member of this new inner hash, and iterate over that rather than the main `%{$self}`